# For what $x$, with $-\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, does $1-\tan^2x+\tan^4x-\cdots$ have a limiting sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

> Given that $-\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, for what values of $x$ does the series
>
> $$1 - \tan^2 x + \tan^4 x - \cdots$$
>
> have a limiting sum? Hence find the limiting sum.

I don't have any real working because I don't know where to start.
I assume you put it into terms of $\cos x$ and use $\frac{a}{1-r}$ to get limit, but I don't know how to get there.

Do I assume a value for x and guess and check?

I'm new and learning how to use Stack Exchange but any help is appreciated with the question and/or website.

Comment: If $|x|>\dfrac\pi4,$ $$\tan^2x>1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given series can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\tan^{2k}(x) = 1 - \tan^{2}(x) + \tan^{4}(x) - \ldots
\end{align*}

which is a geometric series whose common ratio is given by $-\tan^{2}(x)$. Thus it converges when
\begin{align*}
|-\tan^{2}(x)| < 1 \Longleftrightarrow |\tan(x)| < 1 \Longleftrightarrow -\frac{\pi}{4} < x < \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You have the process backwards. First you find which values of $x$ have a limiting sum. Either by the ratio test or from the condition of an infinite geometric series, you have:

$$|-\tan^2 x| < 1 \Rightarrow \tan^2 x < 1 \Rightarrow -1 < \tan x < 1.$$

Keep in mind that $-\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Then you can use $\frac{a}{1-r}$, now you know that the series has a defined limit.